# Simple R-module contradiction

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ be a simple $R$-module, where $R$ is a semisimple ring.
I have proved that $R=I_1\oplus\dots\oplus I_k$ for some simple left ideals $I_1, \dots, I_k$ of $R$.

Let $\phi_i: M\to I_i$ be $R$-module homomorphisms defined as in the proof of the second proposition [on this page](https://simomaths.wordpress.com/2014/12/30/semisimple-rings-and-modules/).

My question is: why is it a contradiction if $\phi_i$ is the zero map for all $i$?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to define the $\phi_i$? As the question is stated now, there is no contradiction, since you can simply take all $\phi_i$ the zero homomorphisms. I suppose you had in mind some particular $\phi_i$'s?

Comment: @moonlight I actually referred to this blogpost https://simomaths.wordpress.com/2014/12/30/semisimple-rings-and-modules/ where the author claimed that it is absurd (contradiction). (Search for the word "absurd" to find the statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maps in question are maps $I_i\to M$, not $M\to I_i$, and they are obtained by restricting a fixed surjective homomorphism $f:R\to M$ to $I_i$.  Since $R=\bigoplus I_i$, every element $r\in R$ can be written as a sum $r=\sum r_i$ where $r_i\in I_i$, and we have $f(r)=\sum f(r_i)=\sum \phi_i(r_i)$.  So if every $\phi_i$ were $0$, then $f$ itself would be $0$.  But $M$ is simple and hence not the zero module, so since $f$ is surjective, $f$ cannot be $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to obtain a similar conclusion by maps from $M\to I_i$?

Comment: Well, it depends on what the maps are.  If they are defined analogously (i.e., as the composition of a fixed injective homomorphism $M\to R$ with the projections $R\to I_i$ that send $r$ to $r_i$), then you can make a similar argument.